# How to use org.apache.cxf with WSDL2JAVA from url?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, wsdl

I'm very new to WSDL. I'm working on a Spring Boot project. I have a requirement to connect to WSDL from a 3rd party service. I want to generate JAVA from WSDL URL. I'm using

```
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
```

I follow the example from https://turreta.com/2018/01/21/generate-java-classes-from-wsdl-files-using-cxf-codegen-plugin-in-maven/

The example option is below,

```
<wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/geoipservice.wsdl</wsdl>
<wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/geoipservice.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
```

But my WSDL source is URL. I've spent on the internet for an hour looking for the option for WSDL url but nothing found yet.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to generate code from a wsdl file ?

If it is. The wsdl file is usually provided by the server

The url rule is usually
`http(s)://serviceurl:port/interface-method.wsdl`

For example [Google adwords](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/call-structure)

https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201809/CampaignService?wsdl

Comment: Yes I do need to generate from the wsdl url.
Can I just copy the content from the wsdl url to a new file ?

Comment: Yes, the wsdl file content is the wsdl address response content